# syntax error when trying to excute select with left join

Tags: mysql

my db has 3 tables as follow:
First table is
**channels**:
id  |  name  |  link  |  group_id

Second table is:
**group**:
id  |  group |  gstatus

I am trying to do a query :

> SELECT channels.id, channels.group_id, channels.name, channels.link,
> group.group FROM channels AS channels LEFT JOIN group AS group ON
> channels.group_id = group.id

even I tried without (AS) like this :

> SELECT channels.id, channels.group_id, channels.name, channels.link,
> group.group FROM channels  LEFT JOIN group ON channels.group_id =
> group.id

but all what I get is

> SELECT channels.id, channels.group_id, channels.name, channels.link,
> group.group FROM channels AS channels LEFT JOIN group AS group ON
> channels.group_id = group.id
>
> > 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> > near 'group AS group ON channels.group_id = group.id' at line 3
> > Time: 0s

so may can somebody tell me what's wrong in my query?

**Thanks a lot for @Akina, the problem was I used a reserved word for my table group, I just changed the name and now all fine.**
regards

Comment: `JOIN group AS group` - `AS group` does not belong here. Also `FROM channels AS channels`.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried with (AS) and without it, and both give the same result.
Here another try,
SELECT channels.id, channels.group_id, channels.name, channels.link, group.group
FROM channels 
LEFT JOIN group ON channels.group_id = group.id

Comment: `GROUP` is reserved word. Either quote it with backticks or rename the table (preferred).

Comment: Yes, as @Akina says, `GROUP` is a part of `GROUP BY`, so your table name is unfortunate.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Akina; YOU MADE MY DAY AFTER TWO HOURS STRUGGELING :::
:-)

Comment: Always rememeber. In the error message you can see a part of SQL text. This part alsays starts **from errorneous place**. So the error is either the most first char/word in citated part or a place between this first char and previous one (which is not citated). And searching the problem in another place makes no sense. In your error message the most first is the word `group` - hence it is errorneously used in this place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  channels.id,
    channels.group_id,
    channels.name,
    channels.link,
    group.group
FROM    channels AS channels 
LEFT JOIN `group` AS `group` 
ON channels.group_id = group.id
```

Use this backtick ( ` )

Comment: not about ticks, I tried it already and did not work, but as @Akina mentioned the mistake is that I used a reserved word for my table (group), I just changed the table name and all works now

Comment: Actually Safwan, you can do that with backtick as described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html . But yeah, changing name is a good choice to :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @sukalogika.
yes now you are compleatly right, only the reserved word group should be surrounded with ticks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to write

`JOIN group AS group` or `FROM channels AS channels`

because the only purpose of `AS` is to define an alias. If you want to refer by original table name then just omit `AS`:

```
SELECT channels.id, channels.group_id, channels.name, channels.link, group.group FROM channels 
LEFT JOIN `group` ON channels.group_id = group.id
```

UPD also `group` must be quoted because it's a reserved word

Comment: I used it because I needed an alias for sure, but I wrote here the shortest I could, but as @Akina said, I think group is a reserved word, thats why

Comment: oh right. `group` is obviously must be quoted :)